# Excel file not opening in sharepoint 2013

Tags: excel, excel-services

I am using SP2013 & created a site. I have used document library to store the documents in my site but the excel documents doesn't open it shows this error:-   "We're sorry. We run into a problem please try again in sometime "
I don know why ! the word & pdf documents open normally. What shall I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the advanced settings for your library? See if the library is configured to open documents in browser by default. If it is switch it to "Open in client application by default" which would fix the issue for time being.

For a proper fix you need to get ULS logs for the error and try to find the root cause there.